# Detectar quando Scrollbar não esta no final da pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou criando um Chat sem refresh que exibe seus resultados em ordem inversa deixando os atuais na parte de baixo e os antigos na parte de cima.

Já tenho o efeito de mover a pagina para o final quando um comentário novo é postado, porem eu preciso para esse efeito quando o usuário estiver movendo o ScrollBar para cima.

Minha ideia era calcular a diferença da altura da div e a posição do ScrollTop, no entanto as propriedades abaixo não pega o tamanho total da div.

Propriedades js usadas:

```
  element.height()
  element.innerHeight()
  element.outerHeight()
```

Só para constar, minha div tem um height de 100% e um overflow auto, coloquei um overflow hide no body também, já alternei essas propriedades mas mesmo assim não obtive o valor real da div.

Alguém pode me sugerir alguma alternativa para esse caso?
Agradeço a todos pela atenção

Comment: O que vc está colocando em `element`?

Comment: Olá, estou estanciando o elemento pela classe usando jquery ou javascript puro.
Eu recebo o valor de height, porem ele se limita ao tamanho atual da tela, eu posso ate dizer que o tamanho é o que renderiza de inicio no browser, depois que a div se expande eu não consigo pegar esse valor a mais.

Comment: Coloca tudo dentro de um span com `display: inine-block` e pegue o `height` do span, tipo: `<div><span style="display: inine-block"> CONTEÚDO </span></div>`

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela dica, eu fiz o processo usando spam e só conseguir pegar o valor que o navegador renderiza de inicio de acordo com a tela, uso um height de 100% no elemento que recebe as mensagens. 

Eu mudei minha logica e conseguir um resultados legal, eu coloque um botão para ativa e desativa o auto Scroll, depois Usando um bind com o evento scroll eu conseguir somar scrollTop + innerHeight e comparar com um scrollHeight dentro de um if. O resultado do if sempre é positivo quando chega ao final do scrollbar. Engraçado que fora do if eu não obtenho o valor real do height.

Comment: Outro detalhe é que usei o ready do jquery e o window.load e também não conseguir pegar o tamanho total da div.

Comment: Uma outra forma é fazer um $.each na div e somar a altura dos elementos filhos.